# ORDER BY (row) DESC

Tags: php

I want to order the "rank" but it doesnt work,
I tried many things but i cant find a solution to this.

```
$query = $handler->query("SELECT * FROM login ORDER BY rank DESC WHERE rank > 4 AND rank < 7 LIMIT 10");
```

- How can I get the code above to work properly?

---

Things I have tried:

- putting `ORDER BY rank DESC` at the end, and;
- removing `DESC`, but that also did not work.

I have no idea how to fix this since the webpage does not even load upon requesting it.

Comment: `select ... where ... order`. if you had error handling on your query call, you'd have been told about the syntax error.

Comment: Yes, your next task (both: learning and implementing) really should be error handling. Or else you will waste your time with wild guessing which is almost certain to lead to superstition and voodoo ;-)

Comment: As an aside, you'll also need to prevent [sql injection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) in your queries.  That doesn't strictly apply to the example in this question, but it's always a concern :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Order by should be after where clause

```
$query = $handler->query("SELECT * FROM login WHERE rank > 4 AND rank < 7 ORDER BY rank DESC LIMIT 10");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
$query = $handler->query("SELECT * FROM login WHERE rank > 4 AND rank < 7 ORDER BY rank DESC LIMIT 10")
```

Comment: I have added my answer 9 secs ahead of that accepted answer. Do I need to delete this?